# mod_rewrite: The rule was not met, when using \?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Suppose I have the following URI:

```
http://localhost:8888/service/bookshelf/book?bookID=1
```

With the following directives configured in httpd.config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule bookshelf\/(.+)\?(.+)$ bookshelf.php?action=$1&$2 [L]
```

This rewrite rule doesn't match, and I can't figure out/realize why. My regex seems fine generally, and the rewrite rule works if I use something other than \?.

Why is this?

I would expect it to output something like:

```
http://localhost:8888/service/bookshelf.php?action=book&bookID=1
```

I know this scheme seems odd, but it's just a map for convenience.

(I have been using http://htaccess.mwl.be to test this rule, but it's output matches how my local Apache/httpd is behaving.)

Comment: search here for mod_rewrite querystring and you will find the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have defined the rules in your server config, then you firstly need to include `service` in the rule, or set a `RewriteBase`. Secondly, the query string is not passed to the request URI, and you technically don't even need to capture it in this case, as the `QSA` flag will do that for you. See the code below that demonstrates this:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?service/bookshelf/(.+)/?$ /service/bookshelf.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In that rule, I have added the beginning/end boundaries (`^` and `$`) and made the trailing slash optional with `/?`. This also appears at the beginning of the rule as the leading slash is included when in the server config context (this way, both the server config and `.htaccess` contexts are satisfied with the rule).

The `QSA` flag was added - this automatically appends the request query string with the rewrite destination.

Now, requests to `service/bookshelf/book?bookID=67` will be internally rewritten to `service/bookshelf.php?action=book&bookID=67`. You can test this in `bookshelf.php` by entering the following:

```php
<?php var_dump($_GET);
```

Comment: In the per-server context(httpd.config), RewriteRule pattern begin with a  slash "/".

Comment: @Eugeny - Thank you, I have modified my answer.

Comment: Wow! I (clearly) didn't realize that query string params didn't get parsed by the rewrite rule. This is magical! Thank you so much!